# How to create a periodic copy of data from OData to Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am trying to make a periodic copy of all the data returning from an OData query into a documentDB collection, on a daily basis.

The copy works fine using the copy wizard, which is A REALLY GREAT option for simple tasks.  Thanks for that.

What isn't working for me though:  The copy just adds data each time, and I have NO WAY that I can SEE with a documentDB sink to "pre-delete" the data in the collection (compare to the SQL sink which has sqlWriterCleanupScript, which I could set to something like Delete * from 'table').

I know I can create an Azure Batch and do what I need, but at this point, I'm not sure that it isn't better to do a function and forego the Azure Data Factory (ADF) for this move.  I'm using ADF for replicating on-prem SQL stuff just fine, because it has the writer cleanup script.

At this point, I'd like to just use DocumentDB but I don't see a way to do it given the way my data works.

Here's a look at my pipeline:

```
{
    "name": "R-------ProjectToDocDB",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "RelationalSource",
                        "query": " "
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSink",
                        "nestingSeparator": ".",
                        "writeBatchSize": 0,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
/// this is where a cleanup script would be great.
                    },
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "columnMappings": "ProjectId:ProjectId,.....:CostClassification"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "InputDataset-shc"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "OutputDataset-shc"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
                    "style": "StartOfInterval",
                    "retry": 3,
                    "longRetry": 0,
                    "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "Activity-0-_Custom query_->---Project"
            }
        ],
        "start": "2017-04-26T20:13:27.683Z",
        "end": "2099-12-31T05:00:00Z",
        "isPaused": false,
        "hubName": "r-----datafactory01_hub",
        "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
    }
}
```

Perhaps there's an update in the pipeline that creates parity between SQL output and DocumentDB

Comment: I already have several instances of "hopeful" scheduling in my data pipeline.  I know I can use a Logic App or a function on a timer, but what we're looking for here is a predictable pipeline that doesn't call for multiple things to "happen to work".

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Factory did not support clean up script for DocDB today. It's something in our backlog. If you can describe a little bit more for the E2E scenario, could help us priorities. For example, why append to the same collection not work? Is that because there's no way to identify the incremental records after each run? For the clean up requirement, will that always be delete * or it might be based on time stamp, etc. Thanks. Before the support for clean up script was there, custom activity was the only way to workaround now, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. To answer your question about the scenario, think of the same scenario as one might have copying to SQL DB, and attempt to get partity with that.  SQL db output allows for a cleanup script, and it identifies some macros like the windows of time.   The JSON has SQL cleanup script, and my specific requirement is just DELETE * from 'table' today, but it could be time-based on the windows in the future as you mention.  My input data doesn't have timestamps, so i'm Limited as to what I can do.  I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Logic App that runs on a Timer Trigger.